# Spring-boot @ConfigurationProperties not loaded

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am Chinese, my english is very poor, but I have a problem about spring-boot that I cannot find answer in China, I hope anyone can help me!!

I have Pojo ShiroFilterChainMap

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ShiroFilterChainMap.PREFIX)
public class ShiroFilterChainMap {
    public static final String PREFIX = "shiro.filter.chain";
    public LinkedHashMap<String, String> map;
    ...
}
```

In below， it is My configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ShiroFilterChainMap.class)
public class ShiroConfig {
    private ShiroFilterChainMap shiroFilterChainMap;
    public ShiroConfig(ShiroFilterChainMap shiroFilterChainMap) {
        this.shiroFilterChainMap = shiroFilterChainMap;
    }
    ...
}
```

META-INF -> spring.factories

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
com.shiwen.shiro.ShiroConfig
```

Next, another project depend on the project,  throw an exception on startup

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.shiwen.shiro.ShiroConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a56527fa.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 33 more
```

if use setter DI,  it also error,  the property injected is null,

In above that is my question, I hope anyone help me, Thanks!!

Comment: have you tried using a default constructor and `@Autowire` `ShiroFilterChainMap`?

Comment: is ShiroFilterChainMap objec is null or the map inside it is null?. You should have `@Configuration` on your ShiroFilterChainMap class

Comment: Thanks you！ I was got the answer,  becuse having a special bean in my configuration Bean -->  LifecycleBeanPostProcessor, delete that and add it in to another configuration,  project is ok,  But  I not know that why!!

Comment: May be  about to AOP